# Why the probability of an event happening exactly k of n trials is not equal to the probability of the event k/n?

Tags: probability

The probability of an event is $\frac{4}{15} \approx 0.26667$.
What is the probability of the event happening exactly 4 of 15 independent trials?

How I calculated it:
According to [Bernoulli trial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial), the formula for the probability of exactly $m$ successes is:
$P(k)=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$

In my case the calculation becomes:

$P(k)=\binom{15}{4}\frac{4}{15}^4\frac{11}{15}^{11}=1365*\frac{4}{15}^4\frac{11}{15}^{11}\approx0.227679$

Is this a correct result or I am missing something?
I am asking because it's counter-intuitive for me. I thought that the probability of exactly 4 events of 15 should be equal to the probability of the event itself - $\frac{4}{15}$.

Comment: The binomial theorem result looks right to me: can you explain why you would expect the probability to be equal to the probability of a single success? I don't quite understand why the relationship between those events would be significant

Comment: To sharpen your intuition: throw a fair coin $200000$ times. Is $\frac12$ the probability on $100000$ heads exactly?... I don't think so.

Comment: @StephenDonovan, I read a book that tells about an experiment in which 4 of 15 people helped another person. Knowing this fact we can calculate the probability of a random person of those helping another person - 4/15. Intuitively I thought it must be correct in the opposite way, so that if the probability of a random person helping another person is 4/15, then it must be 4 of 15 people will help with the probability of 4/15. Now I understand this is not correct

Comment: @drhab, Thank you, this is a good example you gave. Now it's more clear.